# if we cancel the job with savepoint, job got cancelled and savepoint was failure how to restore this job now

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have deployed flink job in application mode using native kubernetes deployment and stopping job along with savepoint (I'm using rest api command for that) but if it fails to complete savepoint is it possible to take savepoint for that job as it was cancelled already?

```
1) success:

{
  "status":{"id":"COMPLETED"},
  "operation":{
    "location":"file:/savepoints-dir/savepoint-ad4025-dd46c1bd1c80"
  }
}
2) failure:

{
  "status":{"id":"COMPLETED"},
  "operation":{
    "failure-cause":{
      "class": "java.util.concurrent.CompletionException",
      "stack-trace": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which flink version are You using ?

Comment: flink version 1.13

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a checkpoint, you can restart from it: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/ops/state/checkpoints/#resuming-from-a-retained-checkpoint